# For Each Loop outputs only 1 result; Trying to output 3 results in array then stop looping

Tags: php, foreach

My `foreach` Loop outputs only 1 result. what I am trying to do is output 3 results from foreach loop then essentially break/stop the loop.

```
  <?php $i=0; foreach($feature_event as $event): $i++ ?>
       <?php if($event["end"] >= $now && $i==3): ?>
                ... CODE HERE ...
       <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endforeach;?>
```

**UPDATE**
Array and Now Variable

```
<?php 
$now = strtotime("now");

$feature_event = array(

    array(
        "title"     => "Cincinnati Music Festival",
        "date"      => "July 22-24, 2016",
        "end"       => strtotime("July 24, 2016"),

    ),
    array(
        "title"     => "Essence Festival",
        "date"      => "June 30 - July 2, 2017",
        "end"       => strtotime("July 2, 2017"),

    ),
    array(
        "title"     => "Magic City Classic",
        "date"      => "October 28 - 30 2016",
        "end"       => strtotime("October 30, 2016"),

    ),
    array(
        "title"     => "NBA All-Star Weekend",
        "date"      => "February 17-19, 2017",
        "end"       => strtotime("February 19, 2017"),

    ),
    array(
        "title"     => "Party Gras Cruise",
        "date"      => "August 18-20, 2016",
        "end"       => strtotime("August 20, 2016"),
    )

    array_multisort(array_column($feature_event, 'end'), $feature_event);
    ?>
```

**forgot to add the array multisort**

Comment: Can you add some code to show the first few entries from the `$feature_event` array, and the value of the `$now` variable?

Comment: And if `$event["end"] >= $now`, should the loop stop even if 3 results have not been output yet?

Comment: the way I originally had it, I didnt have a counter or incrementer , so it output all results in array. what I want to do is have the results that are less than the "now" to display, but only the 3 earliest results....

Comment: I'm not sure how many other values there are in `$feature_event` other than the sample you've added, but there is only one value there with `end` < `now`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seem to get the results I was looking for...

```
<?php $i=0; foreach($feature_event as $event): if ($i == 3) break; ?>
     <?php if($event["end"] > $now): $i++;  ?>
                <div class="event box-fade hvr-float">
                    <a href="<?php echo $event["link"]; ?>" title="<?php echo $event["title"]; ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $event["img"]; ?>" />
                    </a>
                    <h4><?php echo $event["title"]; ?></h4>
                    <p><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <?php echo $event["date"]; ?></p>
                    <p><a class="learnmore" href="<?php echo $event["link"]; ?>" title="Learn more about <?php echo $event["title"]; ?>">Learn More</a></p>
                </div>
     <?php  endif; ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
<?php if($event["end"] >= $now && $i==3): ?>
```

to

```
<?php if($event["end"] >= $now): if ($i == 3) break; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will echo the first three events which are still in the future.

```
$i = 0;

foreach ($feature_event as $event) {
    if ($i == 3) break;

    if ($event['end'] >= $now) {
        $i++;
        echo $event['title'] . '<br>';
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it written with `if($event["end"] >= $now && $i==3)` it will only output when `$i==3`, and that will only happen on one iteration of the loop.

I would suggest this: loop over a slice of the first three items from the array (after sorting it). This way you'll get a maximum of three events.

```
foreach (array_slice($feature_event, 0, 3) as $event) {
    if ($event["end"] >= $now) break;
    // your other code
}
```

You can break the loop on the date comparison condition, but if you really are comparing to `strtotime("now")`, keep in mind that you'll only get past events. I assume that is what you want, but just wanted to reiterate, because based on the sample you provided, only one item would be output even with this code, because only one of those items matches the date condition.

Answer (score 0):

This will make your code to output 3 records (of course, `if $event["end"] >= $now` is true for at least 3 records) but you should look for better solutions.

```
<?php $i=0; foreach($feature_event as $event): ?>
       <?php if(($event["end"] >= $now) && ($i<3)): ?>
                ... CODE HERE ...
       <?php endif; ?>

  <?php $i++; endforeach;?>
```

If your $feature_event is a collection of database query, add a where and limit clause.

```
$query = "SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM `events` WHERE 'end' > CURDATE() LIMIT 3"
```

That way you'll not need to use additional `$i` counter in your iteration.

Or, if you wish to stick with your result set, just use for loop.

```
<?php for($i=0; $i<3; $++); ?>
  <?php if($event["end"] >= $now ): ?>
    <p><?= $featured_event[i]['some_index'] ?></p>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?endfor; ?>
```